# Scheduled tasks created with schtasks are interactive only. How do I create a task on a server that will always run?

Tags: scheduled-task, schtasks

I have a web app deployed with an azure pipeline. Part of the deployment is to create scheduled tasks with schtasks. The line of DOS that creates my task is as follows.

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 10 /tn ScheduledSync /tr "curl https://company.com/api/sync"
```

When I view the task in the task viewer, the checkbox "Execute even if user is not connected" *is not checked*. This is weird because schtasks has a /it flag, to create a task that runs *only if the user is connected*, implying the default is the opposite (if I don't supply /it, it should run all the time????). As things stand, I have no way of specifying or obtaining the desired behaviour - execute all the time. This can't be right? This shouldn't be so hard?